# KD-Tree implementation with lat/lon coordinates

Tags: trees

I have implemented a KD-Tree that stores coordinates (latitude, longitude). I have also implemented a Nearest Neighbor search algorithm using the Haversine distance. My question is, will I get correct results (same nearest neighbor) if I use euclidean distance instead ?

If not, can you give me a concrete example of 3 GPS coordinates (WGS84) where euclidean distance fails to distinguish which coordinate is closer to which ?

Comment: no, you will not.

Comment: @Sasha Can you give me a concrete example of 3 GPS coordinates (WGS84) where euclidean distance fails to distinguish which coordinate is closer to which ? Because I am convinced that this is not possible.